# Is this endgame winnable for white? (Knight vs two connected passed queenside pawns)

Tags: strategy, endgame, knights, pawn-structure

I would like to know if this endgame is winnable for white. Black to play.

[image: The picture of the position is following :]

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What are your ideas? Have you tried something? I don't have time to analyze this properly, but an "obvious" idea is that White will play Na3 and then Black's king's squares are limited so White can take the pawn on a4 and then on b3. OTOH, black will then have time to start eating the kingisde pawns.

Comment: White wins, but it is late and I will go to sleep soon. Maybe tomorrow I will post a solution. Best regards.

Comment: @JiK I Played the Na3 but It seemed to me that I didn't play it Well and I loosed the game, and don't forget that it's black turn, so this can make a difference :)

Comment: Thanks in advance @AlwaysLearningNewStuff it seems you're very confident :p

Comment: I have **thoroughly** checked all the possibilities for both sides, and have concluded that it is a draw. For detailed explanation see my answer. Sorry for misleading you ( in my answer I have explained why I have first thought it was won ). Best regards.

Comment: @mounaim: It seems that you win after all! See my updated answer.

Comment: Ok I'll study it tomorrow in detail :) Thank you for your great motivation for my post @AlwaysLearningNewStuff ^__^

Comment: @mounaim: It IS a draw-I have updated my answer again-this time my update is final. Best regards.

Comment: @mounaim: Member *DagOskarMadsen* pointed out a mistake in my analysis-I have updated my answer to fix it. The endgame is still a draw though... Best regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### EDITED IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT MADE BY MEMBER *DagOskarMadsen*:

Endgame remains a draw, but there was a mistake in my analysis-I hereby thank member *DagOskarMadsen* for pointing it out. I have updated my answer with the proper drawing move, and have left the bad variation as a sideline and marked it with `??` so it can be noticed more easily. I have also more thoroughly analyzed other sidelines which can be seen in my updated comments-some of the variations are highly instructive. I again apologize to viewers of this post for my mistake.

### FINAL EDIT:

I just had a hunch that Black can make a draw based on his strong king-so I had to try finding a solution again. I will post my findings in the section with variations. Also, I will leave the old variations so previous comments will not become useless.

### EDIT:

Edited analysis and the final conclusion in response to member's *DagOskarMadsen* comment.

---

In endgames raw calculation strength comes secondary-the most important skill is to see "the big picture" and your first task is to make **a long term** plan of action. To do that you must analyze the position thoroughly. Only after you have made a plan, you can **verify its correctness** with raw calculation of lines. So let us start analyzing the position above:

The most obvious characteristic is that White has a knight for a two pawns. **However**, that knight is **so badly positioned**. It blocks Blacks pawns, but it is a **weak knight** rather than good one. Why? What is the difference between this knight and a good one? A good knight can block the pawns **and support the execution of the overall plan**-this knight can not do that since Black's pawns will queen if he leaves them unchecked. Whites king is **weaker** than Black one. Whites `g5` pawn has achieved **maximum efficiency**-tying down the entire Blacks king side, but `e3+f2` pawns are weak and are **restrained by one Black pawn**.

As for Black, he has achieved **maximum efficiency** on the queen side, he can not advance further since he has no entry points. His `e4` pawn has achieved **maximum efficiency** as mentioned before ( this pawn also **takes away `d3` square from the White king** which is important for Black's defense-it **reduces** Whites options for *zugzwang*, **disables** White king from penetrating to the king side, and **disables** White from **reorganizing** `e` and `f` pawns for proper defense ). Black pawns on `a4` and `b3` **tie down to defense both king and knight** and have achieved **maximum efficiency** at this moment.

### *Black's plan:*

**Black has advantage** on the queen side, but can **not** capitalize on it. In this situation it is usual to **trade this advantage for the new one**-Black will trade queen side advantage ( `a` and `b` pawns ) for the initiative on the king side.

### *White's plan:*

**White needs to improve his knight's position in order to win**. Knight should **stop Black's counter-play** by **cooperating with his pawns**, allowing king to take all of the Black's pawns. Ideally, White will block **the entire** position and use *zugzwang* to take Black's pawns one by one.

### *The "Big Picture":*

White will need to remove black `a` and `b` pawns in order to be able to free the knight to execute the above plan. To do that White will **lose 4 tempos**-he will need to play `Kb4+Kxa4+Kb3+Kxb2` since Black will surely play `b2!` as soon as he loses `a` pawn. Why? Because if he does not, White will lose only one move to take the `b` pawn by playing `Kxb3` but after `b2!` he will need two moves to do that-`Kb3` and `Kxb2`. **In this position every tempo counts since both sides race to reach the king side first**. We also know that **it is Black's turn to move** so this **adds another tempo**. With **5 tempos ahead**, **a stronger king**, **pawn weaknesses** and **holes** on the light squares-**especially one on `f5`**-we can safely evaluate that **Black will be able to fulfill his plan**- but whether White will have time to improve knight's position and to win the game requires **precise calculation and a strong endgame technique**.

### *The calculation:*

Now is the time to try and verify our conclusions-here are the variations:

```
[FEN "8/5p1p/6p1/2k3P1/p3p3/1pK1P2P/5P2/1N6 b - - 0 1"]

1...Kd5 2.Kb4 Ke5 3.Kxa4 b2! 4.Kb3 ( 4.Nd2 Kf5 5.Kb3 b1=Q+! 6.Nxb1 Kxg5 7.Nd2 Kh4! 8.Nxe4 f5! 9.Nd2 Kxh3 10.Kc4! Kg2 11.f3 (11.f4 h5! 12.Kd3 Kf2! 13.e4 fxe4+ 14.Nxe4+ ( 14.Kxe4 h4 15.Nf3 h3 16.f5! gxf5+ 17.Kf4!! Kg2 18.Ke3!= ) Kf3 15.Nf6! Kxf4 16.Nxh5+!= ) h5! 12.e4 fxe4 13.fxe4 h4= ) Kf5 5.Kxb2 Kxg5 6.Nd2 Kh4! 7.Nxe4 f5! 8.Nf6 ( 8.Nd2 Kxh3 9.f3 ( 9.Kc3 h5 10.f3 h4 11.e4 fxe4 12.fxe4= ) ( 9.Nc4 Kg2 10.Kc3 Kxf2 11.Kd4 h5 12.e4 fxe4 13.Kxe4= ) 9...g5!! ( 9...Kg3?? 10.Kc3 h5 11.e4 fxe4 12.fxe4 +-) 10.e4 fxe4 11.fxe4 Kg4= ) h5 9.Nd5 ( 9.f3 Kg3 10.e4 fxe4 11.fxe4 Kf4 12.Kc2 Ke5 13.Nd7+ Kxe4= ) Kxh3 10.Nf4+ Kg4 11.Nxg6 Kf3 12.Kc2 Kxf2 13.Kd3 Kf3=
```

`14.Kf3` is **the only move** that draws.

The point is that in all variations Black is able to create sufficient counter-play **with the h-pawn** which results in White being forced to give up knight for him ending in a drawn pawn end game or Black simply manages to exchange all pawns.

All the positions were checked with tablebase from [this site](http://www.k4it.de/index.php?topic=egtb&lang=en), so when I put =, it means that I have consulted the **tablebases** as well. I also fully stand behind my evaluations, so if anybody has a question or a comment feel free to ask/comment-I will respond as soon as possible.

The above sample is good enough to give the reader an idea how to save the game. The rest is omitted in order to preserve space.

/******************* BEGINNING OF THE OLD POST *********************/

*This was the old calculation and is left for the sake of not making previous comments ( especially one made by the member **DagOskarMadsen** ) useless. Also, I believe that the variations are highly instructive.*

```
[FEN "8/5p1p/6p1/2k3P1/p3p3/1pK1P2P/5P2/1N6 b - - 0 1"]

1...Kd5 2.Kb4 Ke5 3.Kxa4 b2! 4.Kb3 ( 4.Nd2 Kf5 5.Kb3 b1=Q+! 6.Nxb1 Kxg5 7.Nd2 f5? +- 8.f3 exf3 9.Nxf3+ Kh5 10.Kc4 g5 11.Nd4!+- transposes ) Kf5 5.Kxb2 Kxg5 6.Nd2 f5? +- 7.f3 exf3 8.Nxf3+ Kh5 9.Kc3 g5! 10.Nd4!+- Kg6 (10...g4 11.hxg4+ fxg4 ( 11...Kxg4 12.Kd3+- ) 12.e4+- )( 10...f4 11.exf4 gxf4 12.Nf3+- ) 11.Kc4 Kf6 ( 11...g4 12.hxg4 fxg4 13.e4 Kg5 ( 13...g3 14.Kd5 g2 ( 14...h5 15.Nf5! g2 16.Nh4+) 15.Nf3+- ) 14.e5 g3 15.Kd5 g2 ( 15...Kf4 16.Ne2+! Kg4 17.Nxg3+- ) 16.Ne2!+- ) 12.Kd5 h5 13.Kd6! g4 ( 13...h4 14.Nf3 g4 15.hxg4 fxg4 16.Nxh4 Kg5 17.Ng2! Kf5 18.Kd5 g3 19.e4+ Kg4 20.Kd4! Kf3 21.Ne3+- ) 14.h4!
```

with decisive *zugzwang*.

There is not enough space to show all winning moves **entirely** so I have stopped my analysis **as soon as position arising can be solved with tablebases**. Hopefully you will understand.

/***************** END OF OLD POST ********************************/

### CONCLUSION:

> Is this endgame winnable for whites?

No, it is winnable for White.

Again, I apologize for giving you false information, but I believe that the end game is **highly instructive** and just could not leave it without **thorough** analysis.

Hopefully this answer will help you to learn something new-**I know I certainly did!**

Best regards.

Comment: great analyse @AlwaysLearningNewStuff...Thank you :)

Comment: @mounaim: If this answer solves your problem, consider accepting it so others who see this question can benefit from it as well. I am glad I could help. Best regards.

Comment: Surely it's already done ;)

Comment: @mounaim: Too bad White missed this one :( I really was expecting to find a winning line...

Comment: Actually I was playing this game yesterday. I thought it was a winning position for me. I took the a and b pawns, but then I was not carefull about the black's pawns on the king side and I loosed.

Comment: @mounaim: Too bad... Better luck next time. If you have any other questions-post them her and leave me a comment-I will try to help. Best regards.

Comment: The line `4. Nd2 Kf5 5. Kb3 b1=Q+! 6. Nxb1 Kxg5 7. Nd2 f5` can be continued with `8. f3 exf3 9. Nxf3 Kh5 10. Kc4 g5 11. Nd4`, and this looks winning for white.

Comment: @bof: It is useful to deflect knight from capturing `e4` pawn. This allows Black to capture `g5` pawn without White knight going to `g5`, **with check** and continue taking Black pawns-see the variations above. Of course, if there is a better continuation I will gladly correct my answer.

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen: I think you are right-White does win this. I am updating my answer as I type this. Thank you for pointing out my mistake-I apologize for misleading people with my answer. Best regards.

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen: Although you were right for `Nd4!` winning, I was able to find a draw for Black. I was right-the end game is a draw. Thank you so much for pointing out `Nd4!`, I have learned so much by analyzing this end game. Best regards.

Comment: I am not convinced the variation starting with `8. Nd2` is a draw. The white e-pawn will promote, while there are some tricks with `Nf3!` at the right moment to stop blacks h-pawn or win the new queen with `Qa8+` if the knight is taken.

Comment: While you are at it, maybe you could check my analysis in  the following question :) http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1474/typical-good-bishop-vs-bad-bishop-endgame-how-to-decide-if-stronger-side-has

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen: All variations end up with a draw-`Q+N` vs `Q` = draw. Go to the link I have posted and check the tablebase. As for the endgame you asked me to see-I am looking at it as I type-I will reply soon. Best regards.

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen: In your linked question White wins in 3 moves no mater what Black plays. Best regards.

Comment: I went to the link you posted and put in the position after `12. fxe4` in the variation under discussion. It says `Lose in 18`.

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen: Fixed my mistake-thank you for pointing it out. The endgame is still drawn, but black needs to play **the only move** in order to do it. If you find other mistakes please correct me again. I would highly appreciate it. Best regards.

Comment: At the end of your main line, can you elaborate how Black secures a draw if White plays 13.Kd2!? instead of Kd3 ? both 13.Kd2 Kg3 14.Ke2 h4 15.Nf4 and 13.Kd2 Kf3 14.Kd3 (hoping for Zugzwang) Kf2 15.Nh4 seem non-obvious to me.

Comment: @Evargalo: When analyzing, [this](http://www.k4it.de/index.php?lang=en&topic=egtb) online 6-men tablebase was very helpful. It can answer you better than I can :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a partial answer explaining why Black should abandon his queenside pawns.

Black has no moves on the kingside, so white can take the a and b pawns by using zugzwang: If Black tries to keep his ab-pawns, here's what might happen:

1...Kb5 2.Na3+ Ka5 3.Kc4 Kb6 4.Kb4 and white takes the pawns
or 3...b2 4.Kc3 and 5.Kxb2

If black starts with anything other than 1...Kb5, White has to watch out for the following idea:

1...Kc6 2.Kb4 Kd5 3.Kxa4 Kc4 and now White is suddenly in trouble. (This might be a win for White after all, but these complications are not necessary)

However, after 1...Kc6 2.Kb4 Kd5, White can just play 3.Na3 again and the Black king is blocked on the queenside.

So whatever Black plays now, he's only idea later will be to go to the kingside and start taking White's pawns. And it makes sense to say that that idea should be employed as quickly as possible, starting with 1...Kd5 and 2...Ke5. I assume White has a win even if he loses the gh-pawns but I wouldn't trust it without further calculation.

Comment: A good start of an explanation. Thanks for noticing that Black is in Zugzwang.  Note also, however, that White can move his h-pawn. This is a Zugzwang 'get out of jail free' card given Black is really bound up.  And you're right, Black should abandon his Queenside pawns.

Comment: Note also that White does not have to gobble those Queenside pawns immediately - they cannot advance against the Knight.  This gives White the possibility of attacking the e pawn by Kd4 as soon as Black's King clears the squares on its way to g5.

Comment: Hi JiK have you seen the @AlwaysLearningNewStuff analyse of the game ? I think he is right it's definitely a draw ;)

Answer (score 0):

That endgame is winning for white, all white has to do is get rid of the pawns a4,b3 and try to preserve at least one pawn on the kingside and make it a passed pawn, the knight plays an important role by cutting all black ideas of promoting any pawns

1. Kd5 2. Kb4 Ke5 3. Kxa4 Kf5 4. Kxb3 Kxg5 5. Nd2 f5 6. f3 exf3 7. Nxf3+ Kh5
2. Kc4 g5 9. Kd5 g4 10. hxg4+ fxg4 11. Ng1 Kg6 12. e4 Kf7 13. e5 Ke7 14. Ne2 h5
3. Ng3 Kf7 16. Nxh5 Kg6 17. Ng3 Kg5 18. e6 *

You should aim for something like this

Comment: Thank you @Panzer for replying...But could you please be more specific by giving a sequence of moves..Because I think that taking the a4 and b3 black pawns is not this "easy" :)

Comment: What is this Ng3 move?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Na3 wins this for white.  Black's king is forced back, white's king advances, captures the a4 pawn, and the writing is on the wall for black.

Comment: Welcome to Chess Stack Exchange! It's not so simple, see the accepted answer for a full analysis. Unless you can improve on that analysis, this answer doesn't really add any value to the site.

Comment: @Glorfindel The author of the answer probably thinks it's White's turn, in which case it is indeed easy

Answer (score -1):

The answer would depend on the side to move.
If it is white's turn, white wins with Nd2.
If it is black's turn, it is a draw, the black king picks up the loose g5 and h3 pawns and then the remaining material in insufficient for a win.
It is very dangerous to decide on games outcomes without knowing the side to move.
There are positions in which, depending on the side to move, each player can deliver his opponent mate.

Comment: The question clearly states *Black to play.*